# partition order messed up grub

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, grub, bootloader, testdisk

`testdisk` put my partition table into sector order. Next I ran `update-grub` to rewrite the bootloader. Now every boot lands me at

```
error: no such partition. 
grub rescue>
```

The only thing that gets me booting is the solution
https://superuser.com/a/182194/110335

using **(hd0,msdos3)**

When I run `set` in the `grub rescue` mode above, I see it persists with the former **(hd0,msdos4)**

What should I do to fix this? It's Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 0):

Eventually found it myself.

The command that got it booting properly again was

```
grub-install /dev/sda3
```

Since that was the partition marked active. Also it seems that in grub-speak, *(hd0,3)* and *(hd0,msdos3)* are interchangeable.